# Regex for "or" of multiple words in grep

Tags: bash, unix, regex, grep

```
[Computer]$ grep "foo|bar" filename
```

I understand the above command should return each line in filename where there exits "foo" or "bar". The man pages confirms | as the Regex or symbol and the code works for "foo" and "bar" independently. What am I missing?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

grep uses basic regular expressions (BRE) by default. From the man page:

> **Basic vs Extended Regular Expressions:**
>          In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions
>   \?, +, {, \|, (, and ).

So you either have to escape the `|`:

```
grep "foo\|bar" filename
```

or turn on extended regular expressions:

```
grep -E "foo|bar" filename
```

Comment: I saw that in the man page and misunderstood. I thought it meant that \| would make it look for the complete expression "foo|bar" as opposed to the individual expressions. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: You can also use `egrep` (an alias for `grep -E`) instead of `grep`.