# How to grep words in a file?

Tags: grep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex for “or” in grep](https://superuser.com/questions/436050/regex-for-or-in-grep)

How can I grep for lines with either 'disable' or 'enable' in my file?

I tried 
 $ grep   "disable|enable" fail.log

but that shows up nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `-P` switch for [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) (PCRE).

Try:

```
grep -P "disable|enable" fail.log
```

Without it, `grep` uses [POSIX Basic Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions), which have inconsistent escaping and less features.

Answer (score 2):

Try "grep "disable\|enable" fail.log

The backslash turns the | into the "or" metacharacter, otherwise you are grepping for the literal 'disable|enable"